# Substitute previous row value if value equal to 0 in R

Tags: r

I want to check if the value of a column in a dataframe is equal to 0 and if it is 0, I want to substitute the previous row's value of that column.

Suppose my data is as follows,

```
               X
683           24.48
684           24.48
685           24.48
686           24.48
687           24.48
688           24.48
689           25.02
690           25.02
691           25.02
692           25.02
693           25.02
694           25.02
695           25.02
696           25.02
697           25.32
698           25.32
699           25.32
700            0.00
701            0.00
702            0.00
703            0.00
704            0.00
705            0.00
706            0.00
707            0.00
708            0.00
709            0.00
710            0.00
711            0.00
712            0.00
713            0.00
714            0.00
715            0.00
716            0.00
717            0.00
718            0.00
719            0.00
720            0.00
721            0.00
722            0.00
723            0.00
724            0.00
725            0.00
726            0.00
727            0.00
728            0.00
729            0.00
730            0.00
731            0.00
732            0.00
733            0.00
734            0.00
735            0.00
736            0.00
737            0.00
738            0.00
739            0.00
740            0.00
741            0.00
742            0.00
743            0.00
744            0.00
745            0.00
746            0.00
747            0.00
748            0.00
749            0.00
750            0.00
751            0.00
752            0.00
753            0.00
754            0.00
755            0.00
756            0.00
757            0.00
758            0.00
759            0.00
760            0.00
761            0.00
762            0.00
763            0.00
764            0.00
765            0.00
766            0.00
767            0.00
768            0.00
769            0.00
770            0.00
771            0.00
772            0.00
773            0.00
774            0.00
775            0.00
776            0.00
777            0.00
778            0.00
779            0.00
780            0.00
781            0.00
782            0.00
783            0.00
784            0.00
785            0.00
786            0.00
787            0.00
788            0.00
789            0.00
790            0.00
791            0.00
792            0.00
793            0.00
794            0.00
795            0.00
796            0.00
797            0.00
798            0.00
799            0.00
800            0.00
801            0.00
802            0.00
803            0.00
804            0.00
805            0.00
806            0.00
807            0.00
808            0.00
809            0.00
810            0.00
811            0.00
812            0.00
813            0.00
814            0.00
815            0.00
816            0.00
817            0.00
818            0.00
819            0.00
820            0.00
821            0.00
822            0.00
823            0.00
824            0.00
825            0.00
826            0.00
827            0.00
828            0.00
829            0.00
830            0.00
831            0.00
832            0.00
833            0.00
834            0.00
835            0.00
836            0.00
837            0.00
838            0.00
839            0.00
840            0.00
841            0.00
842            0.00
843            0.00
844            0.00
845            0.00
846            0.00
847            0.00
848            0.00
849            0.00
850            0.00
851            0.00
852            0.00
853            0.00
854            0.00
855            0.00
856            0.00
857            0.00
858            0.00
859            0.00
860            0.00
861            0.00
862            0.00
863            0.00
864            0.00
865            0.00
866            0.00
867            0.00
868            0.00
869            0.00
870            0.00
871            0.00
872            0.00
873            0.00
874            0.00
875            0.00
876            0.00
877            0.00
878            0.00
879            0.00
880            0.00
881            0.00
882            0.00
883            0.00
884            0.00
885            0.00
886            0.00
887            0.00
888            0.00
889            0.00
890            0.00
891            0.00
892            0.00
893            0.00
894            0.00
895            0.00
896            0.00
897            0.00
898            0.00
899            0.00
900            0.00
901            0.00
902            0.00
903            0.00
904            0.00
905            0.00
906            0.00
907            0.00
908            0.00
909            0.00
910            0.00
911            0.00
912            0.00
913            0.00
914            0.00
915            0.00
916            0.00
917            0.00
918            0.00
919            0.00
920            0.00
921            0.00
922            0.00
923            0.00
924            0.00
925            0.00
926            0.00
927            0.00
928            0.00
929            0.00
930            0.00
931            0.00
932            0.00
933            0.00
934            0.00
935            0.00
936            0.00
937            0.00
938            0.00
939            0.00
940            0.00
941            0.00
942            0.00
943            0.00
944            0.00
945            0.00
946            0.00
947            0.00
948            0.00
949            0.00
950            0.00
951            0.00
952            0.00
953            0.00
954            0.00
955            0.00
956            0.00
957            0.00
958            0.00
959            0.00
960            0.00
961            0.00
962            0.00
963            0.00
964            0.00
965            0.00
966            0.00
967            0.00
968            0.00
969            0.00
970            0.00
971            0.00
972            0.00
973            0.00
974            0.00
975            0.00
976            0.00
977            0.00
978            0.00
979            0.00
980            0.00
981            0.00
982            0.00
983            0.00
984            0.00
985            0.00
986            0.00
987            0.00
988            0.00
989            0.00
990            0.00
991            0.00
992            0.00
993            0.00
994            0.00
995            0.00
996            0.00
997            0.00
998            0.00
999            0.00
1000           0.00
1001           0.00
1002           0.00
1003           0.00
1004           0.00
1005           0.00
1006           0.00
1007           0.00
1008           0.00
1009           0.00
1010           0.00
1011           0.00
1012           0.00
1013           0.00
1014           0.00
1015           0.00
1016           0.00
1017           0.00
1018           0.00
1019           0.00
1020           0.00
1021           0.00
1022           0.00
1023           0.00
1024           0.00
1025           0.00
1026           0.00
1027           0.00
1028           0.00
1029           0.00
1030           0.00
1031           0.00
1032           0.00
1033           0.00
1034           0.00
1035           0.00
1036           0.00
1037           0.00
1038           0.00
1039           0.00
1040           0.00
1041           0.00
1042           0.00
1043           0.00
1044           0.00
1045           0.00
1046           0.00
1047           0.00
1048           0.00
1049           0.00
1050           0.00
1051           0.00
1052           0.00
1053           0.00
1054           0.00
1055           0.00
1056           0.00
1057           0.00
1058           0.00
1059           0.00
1060           0.00
1061           0.00
1062           0.00
1063           0.00
1064           0.00
1065           0.00
1066           0.00
1067           0.00
1068           0.00
1069           0.00
1070           0.00
1071           0.00
1072           0.00
1073           0.00
1074           0.00
1075           0.00
1076           0.00
1077           0.00
1078           0.00
1079           0.00
1080           0.00
1081           0.00
1082           0.00
1083           0.00
1084           0.00
1085           0.00
1086           0.00
1087           0.00
1088           0.00
1089           0.00
1090           0.00
1091           0.00
1092           0.00
1093           0.00
1094           0.00
1095           0.00
1096           0.00
1097           0.00
1098           0.00
1099           0.00
1100           0.00
1101           0.00
1102           0.00
1103           0.00
1104           0.00
1105           0.00
1106           0.00
1107           0.00
1108           0.00
1109           0.00
1110           0.00
1111           0.00
1112           0.00
1113           0.00
1114           0.00
1115           0.00
1116           0.00
1117           0.00
1118           0.00
1119           0.00
1120           0.00
1121           0.00
1122           0.00
1123           0.00
1124           0.00
1125           0.00
1126           0.00
1127           0.00
1128           0.00
1129           0.00
1130           0.00
1131           0.00
1132           0.00
1133           0.00
1134           0.00
1135           0.00
1136           0.00
1137           0.00
1138           0.00
1139           0.00
1140           0.00
1141           0.00
1142           0.00
1143           0.00
1144           0.00
1145           0.00
1146           0.00
1147           0.00
1148           0.00
1149           0.00
1150           0.00
1151           0.00
1152           0.00
1153           0.00
1154           0.00
1155           0.00
1156           0.00
1157           0.00
1158           0.00
1159           0.00
1160           0.00
1161           0.00
1162           0.00
1163           0.00
1164           0.00
1165           0.00
1166           0.00
1167           0.00
1168           0.00
1169           0.00
1170           0.00
1171           0.00
1172           0.00
1173           0.00
1174           0.00
1175           0.00
1176           0.00
1177           0.00
1178           0.00
1179           0.00
1180           0.00
1181           0.00
1182           0.00
1183           0.00
1184           0.00
1185           0.00
1186           0.00
1187           0.00
1188           0.00
1189           0.00
1190           0.00
1191           0.00
1192           0.00
1193           0.00
1194           0.00
1195           0.00
1196           0.00
1197           0.00
1198          26.16
1199          26.16
1200          26.16
1201          26.34
```

Here in the 0s, I want the 25.32 value. The point is, initially my data starts at 0.

How can we do this in R?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Provide a piece of your data with `dput`.

Comment: @SabDeM Now I have updated the question

Comment: @akrun This isn't working..

"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: @akrun If the first element is a zero, I'd like to replace it with `NA`, but when `indx-1` contains a zero, the zero is simply ignored in `v1[indx-1]`

Comment: @Frank Yes, I realized it after I commented.

Comment: @akrun why you didn't post your answer? I was hacking with R I didn't see your comment.

Comment: @SabDeM It was still not correct as Frank mentioned it.

Comment: @akrun I do not understand? mine seems to work well.

Comment: @Frank Try `DF$a[w]<-c(NA,DF$a)[w]` instead.

Comment: Thanks @A.Webb -- good call

Comment: @akrun now it works.

Comment: I am still now able to find the solution... I am getting different errors. My first value is 0. How do I do this?

Comment: @haimen It is not clear what you want done when the first row is zero...? I'd be inclined to replace with `NA` (a missing value).

Comment: This is the error I am getting

> ind<- which(sub$count==0)
> sub[ind, 4]<-sub[ind -1, 4]


Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ind, 4, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 761 rows, data has 1563

Comment: I understand the error, but not the behavior you would want to see -- what value should show up in the first row when it is zero?

Comment: I want it to be 0 itself.. It is more like a count. first if it is 0, not a problem, after that whenver 0 comes, I want the previous value

Comment: If there is a sequence 2,0,0 should they all become 2?

Comment: @Frank   Yes I want that kind of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more general solution, that replaces any sequence of zeros with the previous nonzero value:

```
# example
DF <- data.frame(a=c(0,2,0,0,3,0))
#   a
# 1 0
# 2 2
# 3 0
# 4 0
# 5 3
# 6 0

# replacement
library(zoo)
is.na(DF$a) <- DF$a == 0
DF$a        <- na.locf(DF$a,na.rm=FALSE)
#    a
# 1 NA
# 2  2
# 3  2
# 4  2
# 5  3
# 6  3
```

You'll need to install the *zoo* package. This approach overwrites zeros with `NA` and then replaces all `NA`s by taking the Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF).

This is a bad idea if you have any legit `NA`s before this process started and you don't want them treated in this way. You can check that by looking at `table(DF$a,useNA="always")`.

---

**To retain leading zeros.** To keep the first string of zeros as zeros, one could instead do

```
DF$a        <- na.locf(c(0,DF$a), na.rm=FALSE)[-1]
```

again following a pattern suggested by @A.Webb. Use `0L` if `DF$a` is an integer vector.

---

**For nonnegative, increasing variables.** In this special case, @akrun's suggestion will work:

```
DF$a <- cummax(DF$a)
```

This is succinct and doesn't require the use of a package.

Comment: This kind of solves my problem. But there are initial NAs. Need to convert it to 0 after this statement.. Can we do this?

Comment: Sure, you can revert the NA in the first row, like `DF$a[is.na(DF$a)] <- 0`

Comment: @haimen I added an alternative for the last line that should allow you to keep the leading zeros.

Comment: Another idea is `cummax(DF$a)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, I've added a section for that

Answer (score 3):

This approach should work (following a suggestion by @A.Webb):

```
# example
DF <- data.frame(a=c(0,2,0,3))
#   a
# 1 0
# 2 2
# 3 0
# 4 3

# replacement
w    <- which(DF$a==0)
DF$a <- replace(DF$a, w, c(NA,DF$a)[w])
#    a
# 1 NA
# 2  2
# 3  2
# 4  3
```

This approach does not fill in strings of zeroes (not mentioned initially by the OP), which I think require an entirely different approach (posted in a separate answer).

Comment: This one gives the first value as NA. But rest all are same. No other changesin my data

Answer (score 2):

Base R (even though now I've realized the comment of akrun)

```
ind <- which(df$count == 0)
df[ind, 2] <- df[ind - 1, 2]
 df
  id count
1  1     3
2  2     5
3  3     5
4  4     6
5  5     6
6  6     7
```

Comment: @Frank, yes you are right. I did noticed, I have corrected my code.

Comment: This is the error I am getting

> ind<- which(sub$count==0)
> sub[ind, 4]<-sub[ind -1, 4]


Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ind, 4, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 761 rows, data has 1563

Comment: @haimen very strange. Explore the `ind` object and then the `ind - 1` how many elements do they have?

Answer (score 0):

```
> Matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 2, nrow = 4, ncol = 2))
> Matrix
  V1 V2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
4  2  2
> Matrix[2,1] = 0
> Matrix
  V1 V2
1  2  2
2  0  2
3  2  2
4  2  2
> for(i in 1:3)
+ for(j in 1:2)
+ if(Matrix[i,j] == 0)
+ Matrix[i,j] = Matrix[(i-1),j]
> Matrix
  V1 V2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
4  2  2
```

Cant comment so I was unsure by exactly what you meant, but if you were wondering how to query a dataframe for a zero value and replace it with the value from the next row. This approach is only useful for small dataframes. If you have a dataframe with over 1000 cells I would advise using a match() statement where you have a loop over the columns and do something like this ">Match<-match(0,Matrix[,i])". This would tell the location in a row where a match occured and you could implement part of the code above. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Frank Thank you made the change.